# Rendering components are showing up twice when clicked on Add Here button in Sitecore Experience editor

Tags: rendering, sitecore8.2, experience-editor

In experience editor, whenever clicking on "Add here" button, getting duplicate entries of renderings.

Below is the image for reference. I am using Sitecore 8.2

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use Rendering id's to see if the both are same or different. Add the two renderings to the item in two different placeholders and then check the  raw values in the presentation details of the item.

1.If both are same, Then it is caching issue. just clear the cache.

2.If both are different, then there  is rendering available with the same name. If it is a duplicate then copy the rendering id from the presentation details and search it in the sitecore content tree and once you have a hit. delete it.

Comment: The above answer didnt fix it for me.